# Azure Data Collection Rule transformation for TimeGenerated not working

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I have created a Data collection rule in Azure to write data to a custom table. The data is ingested using Log Ingestion API in Azure Monitor. As part of this rule I am transforming the provided "timestamp" field to TimeGenerated. This is done using the following:

`"transformKql": "source\n| extend TimeGenerated = todatetime(substring(timestamp, 0, 23))\n| project-away timestamp\n"`

The timestamp field is in the following format:

`2024-02-07 23:10:05.000 CET`

This works just fine in the Data Collection Rule query builder using the provided sample data. However, when the actual logs come in, the TimeGenerated field is named "TimeGenerated (UTC)" and has the time for when the logs were ingested (very close to _TimeReceived time / now time), rather than the time of the timestamp field.

Has anyone encountered this error? Any help on what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to say that I figured out what was wrong. The reason is the following: "The TimeGenerated value cannot be older than 2 days before received time or more than a day in the future. If in some situation, the value is older than 2 days or more than a day in the future, it would be replaced with the actual recieved time."

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-standard-columns